# How to verify a contextual condition when a method is called with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, conditional-statements

I'm using Moq and I need to check a condition when a mock method is called. Into following example i try to read the Property1 property, but this could be any expression:

```
var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
fooMock.Setup(f => f.Method1())
       .Returns(null)
       .Check(f => f.Property1 == true) // Invented method
       .Verifiable();
```

My final objective is to check if a condition is true when the method is called. How can I perform this?

Comment: Any reasons why you can't just use `Assert.IsTrue(fooMock.PropertyOne)` or something similar before you execute your test?

Comment: if a condition should always be true when a method is called why not put that check in the method and throw an `InvalidOperationException` when it is not true?

Comment: It's a particolar condition setted by action's logic, that has to be valid only when that method is called, not before the starting of action and not after the end. I can't check with an Assert.
This condition doesn't have to be valid always, but into this precise context... I can't use an InvalidOperationException

Comment: It does feel a bit like you are testing implementation details rather than the function here then. My view on testing is that you start the test at some known point, you run the code being tested, you then test that the end point is what you expected. It shouldn't matter how it does what it does, just that it does. Of course I don't know your situation so what I say may not apply for some reasons.

Comment: In detail, I've to enable a "SuperUser" mode during that call. This mode enables exceptional authorizations, and as to be enabled for and only for that call. This mode is not a parameter, so I've to check the context when the call is performed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably use `Callback()`, example:

```
// callbacks can be specified before and after invocation
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Execute("ping"))
    .Callback(() => Console.WriteLine("Before returns"))
    .Returns(true)
    .Callback(() => Console.WriteLine("After returns"));
```

In your case something like:

```
bool isProperty1True = false;
var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
fooMock.Setup(f => f.Method1())
       .Callback(() => isProperty1True = fooMock.Object.Property1 == true) 
       .Returns(null)
       .Verifiable();

Assert.IsTrue(isProperty1True);
```

Comment: I can use an Assert into a callback method! Thanks! I didn't know that difference between callbacks before and after returns.

Comment: You are welcome! First code example is from [here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

Comment: @tmm360 I wonder what the return type of `Method1` is. Using `.Returns(null)` often leads to the wrong overload (the one taking a `Func<>` delegate), or else it leads to a compile-time error (ambiguous). In the first case, Moq tolerates the null func, but it still feels better to use e.g. `.Returns((object)null)`.

Comment: Just so everyone is clear, the following is also possible.  `... fooMock.Setup(f => f.Method1()).Callback(() => Assert.IsTrue(fooMock.Object.Property1 == true))`

Comment: The only issue with using an assert in the callback, is that the test will still appear to pass if the assert is not called.